# Redux saga update a nested array of object state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have a redux slice entity which I am using to store a state of an array. The array itself contains nested properties of array of objects. Now I need to update that state in redux saga and I am have tried to create another generator function but unable to figure out in it how can I update the state. I only need to update the state and API call will be made later. How can I update the state?

Here is the interface of task and deliveryParcels

```
export interface IRiderTask {
  _id?: any;
  riderId: string;
  totalAmount: number;
  riderName: string;
  cityId: string;
  cityName: string;
  status: string;
  adminName: string;
  adminId: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  deliveryParcels: IDeliveryParcels[];
}

export interface IDeliveryParcels {
  parcelId: string;
  processingStatus?: string;
  amount: number;
  orderType: 'COD' | 'NONCOD';
  postedStatus?: {
    status: string;
    statusKey: string;
    signature?: string;
    checkboxData?: any[];
    reason: string;
    adminId?: string;
    adminName?: string;
  };
}
```

I will be updating the postedStatus object each time with different values so need to handle it in generator function of saga.

Here is my saga

```
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  createEntityAdapter,
  createSelector,
  createSlice,
  EntityState,
  PayloadAction,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IRiderTask } from '@swyft/interfaces';
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { select } from 'typed-redux-saga/dist';
import { DeliveryManagementState } from '../state';

export const finalStatus_FEATURE_KEY = 'finalStatus';
type Processing = 'initial' | 'processing' | 'processed' | 'processing error';

/*
 * Update these interfaces according to your requirements.
 */
export interface finalStatusEntity extends IRiderTask {
  _id?: any;
}

export interface finalStatusState extends EntityState<finalStatusEntity> {
  loadingStatus: Processing;
  updatingRequest: Processing;
  error: string | null;
}

export const finalStatusAdapter = createEntityAdapter<finalStatusEntity>({
  selectId: (e) => e._id,
});

export const initialfinalStatusState: finalStatusState = finalStatusAdapter.getInitialState(
  {
    loadingStatus: 'initial',
    updatingRequest: 'initial',
    error: null,
  }
);

export const finalStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: finalStatus_FEATURE_KEY,
  initialState: initialfinalStatusState,
  reducers: {
    add: finalStatusAdapter.addOne,
    remove: finalStatusAdapter.removeOne,
    setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<Processing>) => {
      state.loadingStatus = action.payload;
    },
    setTasksState: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ data: any }>) => {},
    setUpdatedState: (state, action: PayloadAction<Processing>) => {
      state.updatingRequest = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

/*
 * Export reducer for store configuration.
 */
export const finalStatusReducer = finalStatusSlice.reducer;

export const finalStatusActions = finalStatusSlice.actions;

const { selectAll, selectEntities } = finalStatusAdapter.getSelectors();

export const getfinalStatusState = (
  rootState: DeliveryManagementState
): finalStatusState => rootState.deliveryPilet.finalStatus;

export const selectAllfinalStatus = createSelector(
  getfinalStatusState,
  selectAll
);

export const selectfinalStatusEntities = createSelector(
  getfinalStatusState,
  selectEntities
);

export function* finalStatusRootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('finalStatus/setTasksState', setTasksState);
  yield takeEvery('finalStatus/updateTaskState', updateTaskState);
}

function* setTasksState({ payload: { data } }: { payload: { data: any } }) {
  console.log('In slice', data);

  yield put(finalStatusActions.add(data));
  console.log(data);
}

function* updateTaskState(action: PayloadAction<{ id: string; data: any }>) {
  yield put(finalStatusActions.setUpdatedState('processing'));
  yield put(
    finalStatusActions.setUpdatedState({
      id: action.payload.id,
      ...action.payload.data,
    })
  );
  yield put(finalStatusActions.setUpdatedState('processed'));
}
```

Comment: Add first glance this looks correct.  You want to be calling `put` with an action creator and you are.  I'll have to take a closer look at the this later.

Comment: You want to avoid using `string` values when you can.  Instead of `takeEvery('finalStatus/setTasksState')` you can use `takeEvery(finalStatusActions.setTasksState.type)`, etc.

Comment: Sure do take a look, I just need help with the update generator function and how it will be updating data. I am not exactly sure how I will be fetching the already stored data and then update the postedStatus object in it. Since deliveryParcels could be an array of obj. So it is possible that I will be updated processingStatus property in deliveryParcels and at the same time updating the whole postedStatus object

Comment: I'm looking at this again.  In your `finalStatusRootSaga` you want to use the `all` effect from redux-saga.  `export function* finalStatusRootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(finalStatusActions.setTasksState.type, setTasksState),
    takeEvery('finalStatusActions/updateTaskState', updateTaskState)
  ])
}`  Is that the only error?  I suspect there's more.

Comment: Ok there's definitely some incompatible action payload types.  Like you define `setUpdatedState` as having a `payload` of type `Processing` which is a string but you call it in your saga with an object with an `id`.

Comment: You are indexing the `IRiderTask` entities based on an `_id` property which is optional and `any` type.  At runtime you must have a string or number or you'll have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.  One is creating actions and reducer cases to properly update the data.  The other is dispatching some of those actions through the saga.  Quite frankly I don't really understand what your saga is supposed to be doing, and I'm not sure if you do either.  But I can definitely make some improvements.

Do the "processing" states apply to the entire slice, or to each task?

Rather than updating parcels by updating elements of the array I think that it's better to treat them as a separate entity.

saga

```
import { EntityId, PayloadAction, Update } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { finalStatusActions, FinalStatusEntity } from "./slice";
import { put, all, takeEvery, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

// dummy for API call
const postUpdates = async (
  id: EntityId,
  changes: Partial<FinalStatusEntity>
): Promise<Partial<FinalStatusEntity>> => {
  return changes;
};

function* updateTaskState(action: PayloadAction<Update<FinalStatusEntity>>) {
  const { id, changes } = action.payload;
  try {
    const result = yield call(postUpdates, id, changes);
    yield put(
      finalStatusActions.updateTaskStateSuccess({
        id,
        changes: { ...result, status: "processed" }
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : String(error);
    yield put(
      finalStatusActions.updateTaskStateFailure({ id, error: message })
    );
  }
}

export function* finalStatusRootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(finalStatusActions.updateTaskState.type, updateTaskState)
  ]);
}

export default finalStatusRootSaga;
```

store

```
import {
  AnyAction,
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  getDefaultMiddleware
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  createSelectorHook,
  useDispatch as useBasicDispatch
} from "react-redux";
import finalStatus, { parcelSlice } from "./slice";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import mySaga from "./saga";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const deliveryPilet = combineReducers({
  finalStatus,
  parcels: parcelSlice.reducer
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    deliveryPilet
  },
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), sagaMiddleware]
});

sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type DeliveryManagementState = RootState;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export type Action = AnyAction;

export const useDispatch = (): AppDispatch => useBasicDispatch();

export const useSelector = createSelectorHook<RootState>();

export default store;
```

tasks

```
// helper for adding a task
const taskToEntity = (task: IRiderTask): FinalStatusEntity => ({
  ...task,
  parcelIds: task.deliveryParcels.map((o) => o.parcelId)
});

export const finalStatusAdapter = createEntityAdapter<FinalStatusEntity>({
  selectId: (entity) => entity._id
});

export const initialfinalStatusState = finalStatusAdapter.getInitialState();

export const finalStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: finalStatus_FEATURE_KEY,
  initialState: initialfinalStatusState,
  reducers: {
    // accept in the form of an IRiderTask instead of FinalStatusEntity
    addTask: (state, action: PayloadAction<IRiderTask>) => {
      finalStatusAdapter.addOne(state, taskToEntity(action.payload));
    },
    removeTask: finalStatusAdapter.removeOne,
    updateTaskState: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<Update<FinalStatusEntity>>
    ) => {
      // here we just start the update, the saga will dispatch the rest
      const { id } = action.payload;
      finalStatusAdapter.updateOne(state, {
        id,
        changes: { status: "processing" }
      });
    },
    updateTaskStateSuccess: finalStatusAdapter.updateOne,
    updateTaskStateFailure: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ id: EntityId; error: string }>
    ) => {
      const { id, error } = action.payload;
      finalStatusAdapter.updateOne(state, {
        id,
        changes: { status: "processing error", error }
      });
    }
  }
});

export const finalStatusActions = finalStatusSlice.actions;

export default finalStatusReducer;
```

parcels

```
export const parcelAdapter = createEntityAdapter<IDeliveryParcels>({
  selectId: (parcel) => parcel.parcelId
});

export const parcelSlice = createSlice({
  name: "parcels",
  initialState: parcelAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    updateParcel: parcelAdapter.updateOne,
    // handle nested update
    updatePostedStatus: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<Update<IPostedStatus>>
    ) => {
      const { id, changes } = action.payload;
      const current = state.entities[id];
      if (current) {
        current.postedStatus = {
          ...current.postedStatus,
          ...changes
        } as IPostedStatus; // I don't know why this is necessary, but I'm getting TS errors
      }
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // add the parcels when adding a task
    [finalStatusActions.addTask.type]: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<IRiderTask>
    ) => {
      parcelAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload.deliveryParcels);
    }
  }
});
```

types

```
import { EntityId } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface IRiderTask {
  _id: EntityId;
  riderId: string;
  totalAmount: number;
  riderName: string;
  cityId: string;
  cityName: string;
  status: string;
  adminName: string;
  adminId: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  deliveryParcels: IDeliveryParcels[];
}

export interface IPostedStatus {
  status: string;
  statusKey: string;
  signature?: string;
  checkboxData?: any[];
  reason: string;
  adminId?: string;
  adminName?: string;
}

export interface IDeliveryParcels {
  parcelId: string;
  processingStatus?: string;
  amount: number;
  orderType: "COD" | "NONCOD";
  postedStatus?: IPostedStatus;
}

export type Processing =
  | "initial"
  | "processing"
  | "processed"
  | "processing error";

// replace parcel objects with ids, include error
export type FinalStatusEntity = Omit<IRiderTask, "deliveryParcels"> & {
  parcelIds: string[];
  error?: string;
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-updates-ukf0z?file=/src/store/slice.ts)